# Prove that for every finite, nonempty set $B ⊆ A$ there is some $x \in B$ such that $∀y \in B((x, y) \in R ◦ R)$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, graph-theory

> Suppose $R$ is a relation on $A$, and $∀x \in A∀y \in  A(x Ry \lor y
>  Rx)$. Prove that for
>   every finite, nonempty set $B ⊆ A$ there is some $x \in  B$ such that
>   $∀y \in B((x, y) \in  R ◦ R)$. **Below we will refer to such $x$ as LSE of $B$.**

My attempt:

By induction.

**Base case:**

Take $B \subseteq A$ such that $|B| = 1$. Let $B = \{b\}$. Since $R$ is reflexive, $bRb$ and thus $(b,b) \in R \circ R$. $b$ is LSE of $B$

**Induction step:**

Suppose for any set $K \subseteq A$ with $n$ elements exists LSE

Let $B \subseteq A$ such that $|B| = n+1$. Take arbitrary $b \in B$.

Let $B' = B \setminus \{b\}$

By inductive hypothesis, we know $B'$ has LSE, call it $c$.

Consider set $B$.

We know that either $cRb$ or $bRc$

Suppose $cRb$. Since $cRc$, $(c,b) \in R \circ R$. $c$ is LSE of $B$.

Suppose $bRc$

- Suppose exists $a \in A$ such that $cRa$ and $aRb$. Then $(c,b) \in R \circ R$. Hence $c$ is LSE
- Suppose there **doesn't exist** $a \in A$ such that $cRa$ and $aRb$.

  - Since $bRb$, we have $(b,c) \in R \circ R$.
  - Take arbitrary $y \in B'$. We know that $(c,y) \in R \circ R$. Exists some $k$ such that $cRk$ and $kRy$. By assumption, we know that $bRk$. Which means that $(b,y) \in R \circ R$. Since $y$ was arbitrary, we have $\forall x \in B'\bigl((b,x) \in R \circ R\bigr)$.
  - Hence $\forall x \in B\bigl((b,x) \in R \circ R\bigr)$. $b$ is LSE of $B$.

Therefore, in all cases, $B$ will have LSE. $\Box$

Is it correct?

Comment: Suppose $A$ has three elements $x,y,z$ and we have $xRx,xRy,yRy,yRz,zRx,zRz$. Take $B=A$ and the result is false. [Because we do not have any of $xRz,yRx,zRy$.]

Comment: @almagest $x$ will be an LSE there

Comment: For me the proof is correct.

Comment: What does LSE mean?